# populating AutoCompleteBox data from server

Tags: silverlight, events, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using AutoCompleteBox to populate data to it from a server. I've tried at first to do this from TextChanged event, but it crashed my app. I also tried to use KeyUp and KeyDown, but these also didnt work.

this is my code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtWhat.Text.Trim()))
{
     var webClient = new WebClient();
     webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) =>
     {
          List<string> queries = ea.Result.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).ToList<string>();
          Queries.Clear();
          foreach (string str in queries)
               Queries.Add(str);
     };
     webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("www.myserver.me"));
 }
```

the Queries is an ObservableCollection which I bind to the itemssource of the AutoCompleteBox

Comment: Can you post the exception you're getting? This looks OK to me at first blush.

Comment: Its actually acting weird, when I type nothing happens. but when I click backspace, the popup menu blinks for once and disappear.

Comment: Maybe you should access the Queries with a a Dispatcher because you are a different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see this to help you :

[Silverlight Toolkit](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html)

When i used AutoCompleatBox the main events i've tested were DropDownOpened and SelectionChanged...i recommend you use they too.

Hope it helps